# How I can dropdown options when I check on checkbox?

Tags: qt, checkbox, qml

I have one `Checkbox` with `onCheckedChanged` handler and what I want is, when the `Checkbox` is checked, dropdown a menu with several texts and text fields. I have the following code:

```
CheckBox { 
    id: box
    onCheckedChanged: {
        // TODO here to dropdown a menu with settings
    }
}
```

I have texts and text fields like the following:

```
Component {
    id: label

    Text {
        color: "red"
        antialiasing: true
        smooth: true
    }
}
```

I'm a newbie in QML so please be patient.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't really say where this menu is located, if it's floating or if it is to just appear maybe displacing other elements on the view. Anyway, to anwser your question, you can achieve what you're asking by setting the `height` of your 'menu' to zero then, when the `CheckBox` is checked, setting it to however tall you want it to be. To make the menu grow smoothing you can use a `NumberAnimation`.

You can change your `onCheckedChanged()` slot to look like this:

```
onCheckedChanged: {
    menu.height = checked ? 100 : 0
}
```

and add the following, as a child of your menu element:

```
Behavior on height { NumberAnimation {...} }
```

to make the menu's `height` grow from 0 to 100 over a period of time to make it grow smoothly.

---

Another approach, which I'd prefer, is to use [State](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html)s with a [Transition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html) (instead of a Behavior).

Here is an example of a 'menu' which, when the `CheckBox` is checked, will slide out from beneath the `CheckBox`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: checkboxContainer
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: 100
        color: "pink"

        CheckBox {
            id: menuCheckBox
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("Click Me")
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: menu
        anchors.top: checkboxContainer.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: 0 //This is the default value when the 'default' state is active. That is whenever we're not in the "openState"
        clip: true // this hurts rendering performance a bit but is required to make sure child elements don't exceed the bounderies of this object (so when height is zero you don't see the text)
        color: "lightblue"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "openState"
                when: menuCheckBox.checked // This state is only active when the check box is checked. When you uncheck the check box we move to the 'default' state (which sets the menu's hight back to zero)

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: menu
                    height: 100
                }
            }
        ]
        transitions: Transition {

            NumberAnimation {
                property: "height"
                duration: 350 //This means when the height property is changed it will take 350ms to move from what its at to what your changing it to (i.e. 0 to 100 or 100 to 0).
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "red"
            antialiasing: true
            smooth: true
            text: qsTr("HELLO")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.